# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Firefox to toggle viewing the tab bar in full screen mode?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

In Firefox, in full screen mode, you can view the tab bar by moving the mouse cursor to the top of the screen, and hide the tab bar again by moving the mouse cursor down.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to make the top of the screen appear, and a keyboard shortcut to make it disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F6</kbd> will make the bar appear.

After it loses focus, and the mouse is moved a bit, it goes away again.

Source: [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_miscellaneous)

Comment: Is it possible to remove focus from the tab bar, with the keyboard?

Comment: You can move the focus around with the TAB key, but even when you tab focus to the browser pane, it unfortunately doesn't look like the bar will actually vanish until you move the mouse. :/